Google sheet search bar function query
I need to create a function search bar to search a set of data, multiple rows and return a specific value.
Dates are set out in columns and names are in column A. Post codes are shown for each date and down each column (for each name).

I want to search for post code and return the corresponding name.
Tried this:
 =filter('A1:1000,SEARCH(C2,'Copy Cap Plan - last updated 6/8'!A:A))

as a rough example but can only search by name and not postcode.

There might be issues since you have two columns for each date, but you  basically need VLOOKUP on multiple columns.
This can be achieved by first flattening your table to only two columns and then use VLOOKUP on these two columns.
Assuming the postcode you are looking for is in cell C2, this should do the trick:
=VLOOKUP(C2,ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(J9:S17&"|"&A9:A17),"|")),2,0)

EDIT
VLOOKUP will return only one value, even if several names correspond to the same postcode.
To return all occurences/names for the same postcode in the table, we must use FILTER instead of VLOOKUP, on the flattened table again:
=FILTER(INDEX(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(J9:S17&"|"&A9:A17),"|")),0,1),C2=INDEX(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(J9:S17&"|"&A9:A17)"|")),0,2))

INDEX must be used to select the right column from the flattened table.

Great thanks - worked a treat.
So I have multiple names to a postcode would there be a way to look up a postcode and return the multiple names at once

Ok, to return several names we must use FILTER instead of VLOOKUP, see my edit
